# Java - Swing; Progress Bars

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, joptionpane, swingworker

What I want to do is show a progress bar for about 15 seconds, close the dialog, get an ftp reply and display that reply to the user. Here is some of my code:

```
public class testFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {...
   public test() {...
     BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
     bw.setJobNum(jobN);
     bw.setFtpClient(ftpClient);
     bw.setTF(this);
     bw.execute();
   }
}

public class BackgroundWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{...
@Override
    protected void done() {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dispose();
            System.out.println("jobNum: " + jobNum);
            jobOutput = ftpClient.getJobSysOut(jobNum, true);
            System.out.println("jobOutput: " + jobOutput);
            System.out.println("");
            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(jobOutput);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);  
            textArea.setLineWrap(false);  
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 1000, 500 ) );
            textArea.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tf, scrollPane, "Job Output",  
               JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }            
    }
```

If I try to do it the way the codes is written above I get a ftp error that says "Software caused connection abort: socket write error."
However, if I show a message dialog right after bw.execute();

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something", "Job Output",  
                  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

and leave the dialog up until the JOptionPane in the BackgroundWorker is executed, it all works fine. The progress bar dialog closes, the new JOptionPane appears with the correct ftp reply, but the first JOptionPane with the "something" text stays until the user closes it.

My guess is that it has to do with the dialog being modal and not being attached to any parent frame, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Comment: We're not sure how to help you without seeing a short, self-contained, **runnable** example of your problem.

Comment: Yes, that was my concern I know it's hard to answer questions without being able to "see" the problem. I will try to edit this when I get home to include a runnable sample. My worry is that if I down size it it might not act the same, but I guess maybe then I'll figure it out. Thank for the reply!

Comment: "*My worry is that if I down size it it might not act the same, but I guess maybe then I'll figure it out.*" That's the point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to help without understanding the whole code and where is the FTP connection working... but let's try try changing:

`dialog.dispose();`

by:

`dialog.setVisible(false);`

Or try moving the dispose() after getting the FTP Output:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{...
@Override
protected void done() {
    if (dialog != null) {
        System.out.println("jobNum: " + jobNum);
        jobOutput = ftpClient.getJobSysOut(jobNum, true);
        dialog.dispose();
        System.out.println("jobOutput: " + jobOutput);
        System.out.println("");
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(jobOutput);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);  
        textArea.setLineWrap(false);  
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 1000, 500 ) );
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tf, scrollPane, "Job Output",  
           JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }            
}
```

Dispose() method is releasing resources and maybe it close the socket or other kind of afectation to the FTP connection.

If you can edit the example and extend it, it will be helpfull for us to reproduce the issue and help you solving it.